# DataGrid Text auto scroll

Tags: wpf, text, datagrid, autoscroll

In the DataGrid, there is a CheckBoxColumn and a TextColumn, that displays file paths:

```
|   |                              |
| x |C:\docs\etc\somefile.txt      |
|   |C:\programs\misc\files\2.0\oth|   <- cut off, too long
| x |                              |
```

I would prefer if long strings would scroll to the end, so the user can see the filename:

```
|   |                              |
| x |..misc\files\2.0\otherfile.zip|
|   |                              |
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673516/how-can-i-enable-scrollbars-on-the-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution could be to use a textblock in the column template. Set texttrimming to ellipsis and put the long text in the tooltip property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx

If you really want the ellipsis to the left like in your example, you may need to do some code behind measuring, see [Length of string that will fit in a specific width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542717/length-of-string-that-will-fit-in-a-specific-width)

Comment: Thanks.  That last link had the answer I was looking for.